# WSO2 EI (ESB) communicate with WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am new to this software. From what I know, the WSO2 Enterprise Integrator is come with Enterprise Service Bus inside it. But the Identity Server (IS) is not bundled with the EI.

For my current and new project, we going to be used both of it inside the architecture. Please see below diagram for more information.

[Part of my project architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YygK.png)

Based on the diagram, when the user is using the portal to login. The EI is serve as the middle-ware between the portal and the IS to connect to the LDAP.
Looking at the documentation, there is way to connect from IS to the other product but not vice-versa.

My question right here is how to allow the ESB to communicate to the IS and return back the message/request to the Portal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy did not describe your use case what do you want to achieve so I will assume you want to authenticate the portal user or manage users.

WSO2IS (and effectively any wso2 product) exposes *admin services*, some are common, some specific to the product. The services require basic authentication.

please see https://medium.com/@maheeka/wso2-admin-services-c61b7d856272

Another service to authenticate a user is a token service with password grant (that may be more appropriate to authenticate users and authorize requested scopes)

Just a note:
If you want to use the whole setup only only to authenticate users, then IMHO you rather may use OAuth or SAML with the IS, not passing passwords in ESB